# Python-crontab ImportError

Tags: python, installation, cron, importerror

I tried everything getting python-crontab installed via a package manager including but not limited to pip, pyp, apt-get install, easy_install, and they don't return with any error, however, when I run a script it gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crontab.py", line 8, in <module>
    from crontab import CronTab
  File "/home/pi/crontab.py", line 8, in <module>
    from crontab import CronTab
ImportError: cannot import name CronTab
```

I then visited the python-crontab website and downloaded the .tar.gz file, installed it, used the setup.py to install it, and ran their test_log.py and those seem to work. I then curiously places my script inside that folder, and there it works. If it put it anywhere else but that folder, it won't work.

Please tell me this is not normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try renaming the `.py` file to something else. This one - `/home/pi/crontab.py` . This is shadowing the crontab from library.

Comment: You're right, didn't think of thsi at all. Thank you very much!